# Return a typescript interface that changes based on function inputs

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a typescript interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
    property1?: string;
    property2?: string;
};

type InterfaceKey = keyof MyInterface;
```

The code below creates an object based on `MyInterface`. There is a function called `verifyObjectProperty` that allows the user to pass in an `InterfaceKey` ('property1' or 'property2') as a second parameter.

The function validates that the object has a string value for the given key, so it can no longer be undefined.

```
// - Create an object based on the interface
const myObject: MyInterface = {
    property1: 'a string',
}

const verifyObjectProperty = (
    objectToVerify: MyInterface,
    properyToVerify: InterfaceKey
): MyInterface => {
    // - Make sure object has the desired property
    if (objectToVerify[properyToVerify] === undefined) {
        objectToVerify[properyToVerify] = 'a new string';
    }

    // - Return the object
    return myObject;
};
```

I want to make it so the `verifyObjectProperty` function returns a typescript interface that shows which string is guaranteed to be there.

```
const verifiedObject = verifyObjectProperty(myObject, 'property1');
type property1 = typeof verifiedObject['property1']; // string
type property2 = typeof verifiedObject['property2']; // string | undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ts conditional types and mapped types. These features allow you to create new types based on the properties of existing types.

First, create a helper type that will take a property key and return a new type with that property guaranteed to be a string.

```
type EnsureString<T, K extends keyof T> = T & { [P in K]: string };
```

This type takes two parameters: `T` is the original type (`MyInterface`), and `K` is the key of the property you want to check as a string. It returns a new type that is the same as `T`, but with the property `K` guaranteed to be a string.

Then, modify `verifyObjectProperty` to use this helper type.

```
const verifyObjectProperty = <K extends keyof MyInterface>(
   objectToVerify: MyInterface,
   propertyToVerify: K
): EnsureString<MyInterface, K> => {
   // - Make sure object has the desired property
   if (objectToVerify[propertyToVerify] === undefined) {
       objectToVerify[propertyToVerify] = 'a new string';
   }

   // - Return the object
   return objectToVerify as EnsureString<MyInterface, K>;
};
```

After calling `verifyObjectProperty`, it will infer that the returned object has a string value for the specified property.

```
const verifiedObject = verifyObjectProperty(myObject, 'property1');
type property1 = typeof verifiedObject['property1']; // string
type property2 = typeof verifiedObject['property2']; // string | undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where `myObject` comes from in your example, so I figured it is `objectToVerify`.

This seems to work as specified in the TypeScript playground:

```js
interface MyInterface {
  p1?: string;
  p2?: string;
};

function ensureProperty<TProp extends keyof MyInterface>(x: MyInterface, p: TProp) {
  if (x[p] === undefined) {
    x[p] = 'a'
  }
  return x as Omit<MyInterface, TProp> & Record<TProp, string>;
}

var test = ensureProperty({}, 'p2');
```

It uses `Omit<>` to remove the ensured property, which is re-added in the cast when returning the object.